# How to add Selenium Docs to RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using RubyMine 2016.2.4 and looking for a Selenium Doc that I can add to the project. It is better for code completion and suggestions. Any ideas? I refer to this web page for help, but how do I add the doc to the project? https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver

Comment: Not sure why do you want to add the doc to your project. You can just provide the link your post in your README.md file.

Comment: How can adding it to my README helps me with my code completion? @supputuri

Comment: what do you mean by code completion, I thought you are referring to that link to understand the implementation/available methods. Sorry, I did not get it correctly.

Comment: @supputuri Code Completion = Give me suggestion of which methods to use from Selenium Web Driver as I'm typing. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/auto-completing-code.html

Comment: Got you. I have been using the `live templates` for a while, but never tried to load the selenium doc itself. Interesting question...